# PHP Array Improvement

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

Quick question, most likely for a veteran will be easy, or maybe im asking for too much.

i have this code for laravel in php, im not fan to do a foreach, is there a better way? i guess should be an existing function that replace my values of arr to the keys match on arr2, but i dont know

Its really important not to change the order.

```
$arr=  ['filters', 'repeat', 'via', 'type'];
$arr2= [
        'filters' => 'text1',
        'repeat' => 'text2',
        'via' => 'text3',
        'type' => 'text4',
    ];

foreach($arr as $k)
    $res[]=$arr2[$k];

return $res;
```

Comment: another way `$res = array_intersect_key($arr2, array_flip($arr));`, so that you don't lose the matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `array_map`.

```
$arr=  ['filters', 'repeat', 'via', 'type'];
$arr2 = [
    'filters' => 'text1',
    'repeat' => 'text2',
    'via' => 'text3',
    'type' => 'text4',
];

$res = array_map(function($key) use($arr2) {
    return $arr2[$key];
}, $arr);

print_r($res);
```

Comment: Yes, quite clean and looks profesional, this is what i was looking for, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravel's `array_only` helper function:

```
$res = array_only($arr2, $arr);
```

If you don't want to preserve the keys then you can use the `array_values` function too:

```
$res = array_values(array_only($arr2, $arr));
```

Comment: but its not always in same order

Answer (score 2):

Yes, two ways:

1. Use [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/array_values), assuming the values of `$arr` are exactly in the same order as the keys in `$arr2` and always have the same keys. I'm guessing this is not exactly what you meant, but that's what your example shows. If that's the case, then it is as simple as:

```php
    $res = array_values($arr2)
```

2. Use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map) to map the values of one array (in this case `$arr`) to a new array (`$res`):

```php
    $mapper = function($k) use ($arr2) {
        return $arr2[$k];
    };
    $res = array_map($mapper, $arr);
```

You can then also add handling of cases where `$k` does not exist in `$arr2`, e.g. return null and then use `array_filter` to filter out the null values;

(I did not test this code but generally, this is the approach)

Comment: This is good, and yes i can add a null option, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) in Laravel

```
$res = collect($arr)->map(function ($key) use ($arr2) {
    return $arr2[$key];
})->toArray()
```

Comment: This would be great to keep it as a collection, ill keep this in mind, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the array values you can use the `array_values()` function.

```
$arr2= [
        'filters' => 'text1',
        'repeat' => 'text2',
        'via' => 'text3',
        'type' => 'text4',
 ];

$res = array_values($arr2);
```

This will result in the following array:

```
['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']
```

Comment: but you are ignoring the first array

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote, as the example in your question is unclear. The case you provided will work just fine with `array_values()`. Next time, provide a more comprehensive example.